# How to get mercurial commit sequence number in a branch

Tags: mercurial, branch, version, commit

I want to retrieve commit order number, counting ONLY commits of specific branch (master).
As a branch "master" is the same on each machine/repo, then this will allow me to:
 1. Have the same number regardless of the repository
 2. Use this number in a version string.

So, is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just interest: why not latesttag+latesttagdistance?

Comment: Don't know, first time see it. Will investigate now

Comment: Commit order on a branch can still differ from repository to repository depending on the order in which various forks of a branch were committed/pulled.

Comment: can't imagine this. how is it possible?

Comment: If history on that branch ever diverged (multiple heads), which is pretty common then the "commit order number" for a specific revision will differ depending which of those heads were pulled first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hg log -b master --template "." | wc -m` for example

Output **current** amount of changesets in branch

Answer (score 2):

Your idea wont work, even though you limit yourself to a single named branch. As mentioned by Ry4an, the problem is that the order of changesets on that branch is determined by the order of `hg push` and `hg pull`. So you can easily end up with a situation where you have:

```
@    branch: master, changeset: 5:f5b6808f2f04, summary: merge
|\
| o  branch: master, changeset: 4:2b7bdcc98a88, summary: mmm
| |
o |  branch: master, changeset: 3:6b60342a01a6, summary: mm
|/
o  branch: master, changeset: 2:f39fa3fa1aaf, summary: m
|
o  branch: master, changeset: 1:4dd5e8ae6481, summary: create master
|
o  branch: default, changeset: 0:68b4eb1ca123, summary: a
```

in one repository, but

```
@    branch: master, changeset: 5:f5b6808f2f04, summary: merge
|\
| o  branch: master, changeset: 4:6b60342a01a6, summary: mm
| |
o |  branch: master, changeset: 3:2b7bdcc98a88, summary: mmm
|/
o  branch: master, changeset: 2:f39fa3fa1aaf, summary: m
|
o  branch: master, changeset: 1:4dd5e8ae6481, summary: create master
|
o  branch: default, changeset: 0:68b4eb1ca123, summary: a
```

in another. Note how the `mm` and `mmm` changesets are swapped in the two repositories.

It is only if the branch has the same heads in both repositories that you can talk about the "branch being the same" in each repository. If that is the case, then, as suggested by Lazy, a simple

```
hg log -b master --template "." | wc -m
```

will give the same count in both repositories.